# Modify data in a database backup file

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have a .bak file of a database that contains PHI located on a server in a PHI environment. I have a .r script that will anonymize and remove PHI data in the database and any other connections strings that point to client systems. Is there a way to run this script (or another type of script) to modify the .bak file in the PHI environment **before** I move it to a non-PHI compliant environment to be restored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that a ".bak file" is a backup (there is no standard Progress-wide naming convention but that is a common usage).  If so then, no, there is no way to directly manipulate the backup without restoring it.

You could restore it in a safe environment, modify the contents of the restored db and then make a  new backup of the anonymized database.  (If I were to do something like that I would use a different extension, perhaps .BKX, for the scrubbed backup so that it is obvious to people which one is which - that would help to reduce the chances of accidental release...)

Comment: Yes, sorry I thought .bak was the standard naming convention for backups. Your answer is the current process I use. Some of the backups when restored are up to 1.5 tb in size, which makes this process extremely time consuming.... Thanks for the help Tom!

Comment: Yup, that would be time consuming all right.  You could perhaps reduce the pain a bit if the intermediate db were kept continuously ready by way of after-image logs or replication.  You'd still have to refresh it after a scrubbing but at least you wouldn't have to wait for the initial backup & restore.

Comment: 11.7 will see the advent of Change Data Capture. I wonder if this is something you could make use of to create a real time replica that is scrubbed for backing up?